# Can i assign a integer to a character pointer array?

Tags: c, malloc

```
int k=5;
char* result = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
result[count] = k;
```

Considering the above code, if I print the contents of `result[count]` it prints smiley symbols. I tried like below,but of no use.

```
result[count]=(char)k;
```

Can anyone help me?

I am percepting that `malloc(100*sizeof(char))` will create `100` blocks each of size of character contiguously. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Is this a C or a C++ question?

Comment: Use `sprintf`  or `snprintf` .

Comment: FYI: in C, `'$'` (and `'a'` and `'1'` ...) is a value of type `int` (try printing `sizeof '$'`).

Comment: Pick.. one.. language..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Instead of whining about this in every post, why don't you simply edit it and remove the tag which seems least on topic? If the op doesn't like it and have a rationale about why there should be 2 language tags, they can edit it back. No big deal. I'll do it and remove the C++ tag here, since you shouldn't be using malloc in C++ anyhow.

Comment: @Lundin: I have quite good reasons for that, so thanks for doing minimal fact-checking before launching into a personal attack. Firstly, [your follow-upaction is inappropriate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185620/155739): it is generally accepted that it is up to the OP to tell us which language they are using. We shall not "guess" or magically divine that on their behalf. Furthermore, simply editing the tag yourself does nothing to educate the user and stop them from double-tagging in the future. So, no, I am not "whining".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I generally agree with you on that topic, because C and C++ **are** different languages. But here the relevant part `int k = 5; char c=i;` is the same in C and C++, and the `malloc` line would be accepted by C and C++ compilers (even if the cast should not be here in C) - Ok , it would also be the same in java (apart from `malloc`)...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Now, posting [aggressive comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990865/does-any-variable-and-any-variable-can-give-same-result-considering-that) in capital letters is what's inappropriate, and since I read that post just before this one, I dropped the comment. If this is such a big pet peeve of yours and you refuse to edit, simply ignore all such posts and move on?

Comment: @Lundin: I repeat again, it's best to _inform_ and _educate_ while _requesting_ the OP tag the question properly. How on earth could we accomplish that by "ignoring it and moving on?" I concede the bold caps were a likely-inappropriate yet jocularly-intended expression of boiling-point frustration with the constant stream of [tag:c] [tag:c++] double-tagging that just _has_ to stop! Now, would you please follow your own advice, and simply ignore all my comments and move on? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll disregard all the fluff about arrays and malloc as it is irrelevant to the problem you describe. You seem to essentially be asking "What will this code print:"

```
char c = 5; 
printf("%c", c);
```

It will print the symbol 5 in your symbol table, most likely a non-printable character. When encountering non-printable characters, some implementations choose to print non-standard symbols, such as smileys.

If you want to print the number 5, you have to use a character literal:

```
char c = '5';
printf("%c", c);
```

or alternatively use poor style with "magic numbers":

```
char c = 53;   // don't write code like this
printf("%c", c);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem of character representation. Let's begin by the opposite first. A `char` can be promoted to an `int`, but if you do you get the representation of the character (its *code*). Assuming you use ASCII:

```
char c = '5';
int i = c; // i is now 0x35 or 53 ASCII code for '5'
```

Your example is the opposite, 5 can be represented by a char, so `result[count] = k` is defined (even if you should have got a warning for possible truncation), but ASCII char for code 5 is control code ENQ and will be printed as `♣` on a windows system using code page 850 or 437.

A half portable (not specified, but is known to work on all common architectures) way to do the conversion `(int) 5` -> `(char) '5'` is to remember that code '0' to '9' are consecutive (as are 'A' to 'Z' and 'a to 'z'), so I think that what you want is:

```
result[count] = '0' + k;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clean up your code a bit:

```
int k=5;
char* result = malloc(100);
result[count] = k;
```

sizeof(char) is always equal to 1 under any platform and you don't need to cast the return of malloc() in C.

This said, as long as your `count` variable contains a value between 0 and 99, you're not doing anything wrong. If you want to print the actual character '5', then you have to assign the ASCII value of that character (53), not just the number 5. Also, remember that if that array of chars has to be interpreted as a string, you need to terminate it with '\0':

```
int k=5, i;
char* result = malloc(100);
for (i=0; i<98; i++) {
    result[i] = ' ';
}
result[98] = 53;
result[99] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", result);
```

Answer (score -1):

The elements in the array you're trying to allocate are all the size of a char, 1 byte. An int is 4 bytes thus your issues. If you want to store ints in an array you could do:

```
int result[100];
```

Followed by storing the value, but honestly from the way your questioned is posed I don't know if that's actually what you're trying to do. Try rephrasing the post with what you're trying to accomplish.

Are you trying to store 5 as a character?

Comment: If you store an int inside a char, the result will get truncated if needed. It is perfectly well-defined behavior. And not the cause of the problem either.

Comment: @Lundin I never said it wasn't well defined behavior, but it certainly might give someone unexpected results if they tried to store an int in a char array while expecting it to store "5". And yes, I understand that wasn't his issue. I wouldn't exactly say the question was well poised hence my asking him for clarification in my last question.

Comment: (I didn't downvote) Please use comments when asking for clarification, answers are reserved for answering the question.